# How to add xml-stylesheet declaration to parsed XML?

Tags: javascript, xml

I have XML document that was parsed to DOM object like this:

```
const contentDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
```

How can I add/prepend following xml-stylesheet directive to it?

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
```

I want to visualize provided XML file using XSLT stylesheet (that is also provided for me) and I do not want to play with strings (I could potentially just add this declaration with simple string operations before the XML becomes DOM) but I would like to do this properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use **XSLTProcessor()** method to import the Stylesheet.
After you import the XSL, transform the xml to fragment with **"transformToFragment()"** or **"transformToFragment()"** to transform the document with your XSL.

After all, you just add the transformed fragment/document to your desired element.

[Refer to this example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/XSLT_JS_interface_in_Gecko/Basic_Example)
[Also this can help you understand the use of transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Using_the_Mozilla_JavaScript_interface_to_XSL_Transformations)

*I replicated the example they have and is working properly based on your needs, this can solve your request.*

This is what they do:

```
function Init(){

  // load the xslt file, example1.xsl
  var myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "example1.xsl", false);
  myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);

  xslStylesheet = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslStylesheet);

  // load the XML file, example1.xml
  myXMLHTTPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myXMLHTTPRequest.open("GET", "example1.xml", false);
  myXMLHTTPRequest.send(null);

  xmlDoc = myXMLHTTPRequest.responseXML;

  var fragment = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);

  document.getElementById("example").textContent = "";

  myDOM = fragment;
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(fragment);
}
Init();
```

Comment: To test by yourself, create an xml file with "example1.xml", other file with your stylesheet "example1.xsl" and an HTML with your placeholder and the js scripts to process the request.

Comment: Actually that was my first attempt (but with a bit more modern js API like fetch) but unfortunately I have extremely complex stylesheet with external dependencies and it fails on importStylesheet (what's interesting error can be seen only in Firefox, chrome just returns null from transformToFragment). And the stylesheet works if is applied through <?xml-stylesheet  hence my question how to add this declaration to existing DOM model before injecting it into iframe.

Comment: Ok, I have managed to get importStylesheet working - it was problem with providing external stylsheets (they were included with import tag). Now I have different problem - how to get import tag working with unknow base urls :)